# VW Golf 6: Strange humming noise at increased speed

Tags: noise, vw, golf

I have the following problem:
For some time now, my VW Golf 6 has been experiencing a strange humming sound while driving.

- This hum **only** occurs at increased speeds. From about 50 kph (31 mph) quietly and from 80 kph (50 mph) significantly louder. So the faster I drive, the louder it hums.
- The noise seems to be independent of the accelerator. (e.g. when I accelerate at low speeds the noise is not audible).
- The humming noise seems to me maybe caused by a component that is spinning. At least it sounds like it.
- Not a single warning light is flashing. There are also no other problems with the car.

The noise started 2 weeks ago and the intensity has increased since then.
I would greatly appreciate any guesses as to the cause of the problem!
At least about the guess on individual components or the exclusion of some components.

Comment: If you can do so safely, what happens if you drive at 80-90 kph to hear the loud hum, then shift to neutral and coast at that speed? Does the loud hum continue or does it suddenly stop? This test will help to determine whether to concentrate on the engine and transmission or on wheel bearings and CV joints, or even a loose plastic cover or shield that is catching the wind and rubbing on a tire or on the ground. NOTE: Do not shift into PARK while the vehicle is moving. (No offense intended, just being cautious!)

Comment: Some autos don't like coasting in neutral, and another test you can make to determine whether the hum is dependant on road speed or engine speed, is by shifting to another gear at a steady speed. This should reveal which side of the gearbox is causing the hum (if it isn't the gearbox itself): the running gear, or engine components (eg alternator).